# Logging where the QUIT command comes from in IRC

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, irc

So I'm writting an IRC bot in Python. Right now, the first thing I'm trying to get it to do is Log all the important things in every channel it's on (as well as private messages to the bot itself).

So far I've gotten it to log the `JOIN`, `PRIVMSG` (including `CTCP` commands) and `PART`. However I'm having some trouble with the `QUIT` command. Now I know the `QUIT` command doesn't include the `<channel>` parameter because it doesn't need it. However my bot is connected to multiple channels and I need to be able to differentiate which channels the user was connected to when he/she issued the `QUIT` command to appropriate log it. Many users won't be connected to every channel the bot is.

What would be the ideal way to go about this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you care? Either log just that user@host quit (if you logged joins, the channels this user joined will be known) or keep a per-user record in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write the same `QUIT` log message to multiple per-channel log files, but only specific ones the bot is in?

To accomplish something similar, I ended up getting the list of names in a channel when the bot joins, then keeping track of every nick change, join, part, kick, and quit, and adjusting the bot's internal list. That way, on a quit, I could just check the internal list and see what channels they were on.

Comment: Yeah, it seems this is the best way to go about it. Thanks.